Switch component is not working after switching from Checkbox
I was using Ant Design Checkbox earlier to check and publish the comments and it was working fine with no errors.
<Checkbox
  key={record.id}
  checked={Publish[record?.id]?.["ispublish"] == 'true' ? true : false}
  onChange={(e) => Update(e.target.checked, record)}
/> 

I want to use Switch instead.
<Switch
  key={record.id}
  checked={Publish[record?.id]?.["ispublish"] == 'true' ? true : false}
  onChange={(e) => Update(e.target.checked, record)}
/> 

I am getting error:

cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'checked)

I want Switch to work.

The onChange prop callback for the Switch component takes two arguments. The first is the current checked value and the second is the onChange event object.
See the Switch component API:



Property
Description
Type




onChange
Trigger when the checked state is changing
function(checked: boolean, event: Event)



Compared to the CheckBox component API:



Property
Description
Type




onChange
The callback function that is triggered when the state changes
(e: CheckboxChangeEvent) => void



Update to use the first argument, checked:
<Switch
  key={record.id}
  checked={Publish[record?.id]?.ispublish == 'true'}
  onChange={(checked) => Update(checked, record)}
/>

